Ampleness detected by the first Chern class?
Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold. By Kodaira's embedding theorem, a line bundle $L$ on $M$ is ample if and only if its holomorphic de Rham first Chern class $c_1(L)\in H_{\operatorname{dR}}^2(M)$ is positive. In brief, the ampleness of line bundles is completely determined by its holomorphic de Rham first Chern class. I wonder the following algebro-geometric version:

Let $k$ be a base ring, $X$ a smooth $k$-scheme, and $L$ a line bundle on $X$. Then for what cohomology theory, the ampleness of $L$ can be read off from the first Chern class $c_1(L)$?

Here are some remarks and specializations of this question:

It is tautological if we take the motivic cohomology, since the first motivic cohomology classifies line bundles. I am more interested in the results for "weaker" cohomology theories such as de Rham or Hodge-filtered de Rham.

Kodaira's embedding theorem tells us that, when $k=\mathbb C$, for smooth proper $\mathbb C$-schemes $X$, we can simply take the cohomology theory to be the de Rham cohomology. However, for non-proper $X$'s, the positivity does not seem to imply the ampleness in analytic situations:
Takeo Ohsawa, A counter example of ampleness of positive line bundles.
This does not seem to exclude the possibility that the ampleness could read off from the first algebraic de Rham Chern class. In any case, I wonder whether the Hodge-filtered de Rham first Chern class is enough to detect the ampleness?

Any known results in this direction in char $p$ or even in mixed characteristic?



When the characteristic of $k$ is positive, the algebraic de Rham class is not enough to detect ampleness.  However, the cycle class in $\ell$-adic cohomology is enough to detect ampleness.

@JasonStarr Do you mean fix a prime $\ell$, or running through all $\ell$'s? We do have $R\Gamma_{\operatorname{ét}}(X;\mathbb G_m)\ell^\wedge=R\Gamma{\operatorname{ét}}(X;\mathbb Z_\ell(1))$ by definition, but I am not sure whether the $\ell$-completion is enough to detect ampleness?

For any prime $\ell$ different from the characteristic.

@JasonStarr Thanks. Do you have a reference (for the insufficiency of de Rham and sufficiency of $\ell$-adic)? Does that also work for $p$ where we replace the étale cohomology by the syntomic cohomology (we know that the first Chern class induces an equivalence $R\Gamma_{\operatorname{ét}}(X;\mathbb G_m)p^{\wedge}\simeq R\Gamma{\operatorname{syn}}(X;\mathbb Z_p(1))[1]$ for $p$-adic formal schemes $X$, as in Bhatt–Lurie), but I am pretty ignorant on ampleness to tell whether this is enough.

The algebraic de Rham classes take values in a vector space over a characteristic $p$ field (when $k$ has characteristic $p$).  So the first Chern class of $L$ equals the first Chern class of $(L^\vee)^{\otimes(p-1)}$.  So there cannot be an ampleness criterion based on this.  For $\ell$-adic classes, we have the Nakai-Moishezon criterion.

@JasonStarr Thanks. It seems to me that the usual formulation of the Nakai–Moishezon criterion needs properness. Is this the properness eliminable?

I am not sure what happens in the non-proper case . . .
